# MongoDB Automation Agent slow query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-atlas

I have some problems with my DB performance.
My MongoDB query profiler (in Mongo Atlas) shows some queries which executes more than 1.4 sec. How can I optimize those queries and where are they coming from? It's not coming from my project and it seems it is a system one, according to appName attr.

Please view the query down bellow. I got it from query profiler.

```
{
  "appName": "MongoDB Automation Agent v11.14.3.7482 (git: <some hash>)",
  "command": {
    "aggregate": "user_activity_logs",
    "maxTimeMS": 15000,
    "pipeline": [
      {
        "$sample": {
          "size": 200
        }
      }
    ],
    "cursor": {},
    "lsid": {
      "id": {
        "$binary": ".../==",
        "$type": "03"
      }
    },
    "$clusterTime": {
      "clusterTime": {
        "$timestamp": {
          "t": 1652269294,
          "i": 1
        }
      },
      "signature": {
        "hash": {
          "$binary": "PHh4eHh4eD4=",
          "$type": "00"
        },
        "keyId": {
          "$numberLong": "7059743885961986051"
        }
      }
    },
    "$db": "DB_NAME",
    "$readPreference": {
      "mode": "primaryPreferred"
    }
  },
  "planSummary": [
    {
      "MULTI_ITERATOR": {}
    }
  ],
  "cursorid": {
    "$numberLong": "4201428729746214315"
  },
  "keysExamined": 0,
  "docsExamined": 0,
  "numYields": 101,
  "nreturned": 101,
  "reslen": 27597,
  "locks": {
    "ReplicationStateTransition": {
      "acquireCount": {
        "w": 103
      }
    },
    "Global": {
      "acquireCount": {
        "r": 103
      }
    },
    "Database": {
      "acquireCount": {
        "r": 103
      }
    },
    "Collection": {
      "acquireCount": {
        "r": 103
      }
    },
    "Mutex": {
      "acquireCount": {
        "r": 2
      }
    }
  },
  "storage": {
    "data": {
      "bytesRead": 329371839,
      "timeReadingMicros": 1450080
    },
    "timeWaitingMicros": {
      "cache": 277
    }
  },
  "protocol": "op_msg",
  "millis": 1549,
  "v": "4.2.19"
}
```